# Elasticsearch Indices keeps getting lost

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I have an Elasticsearch cluster on AWS ec2 instance. It is **`t3.small`** with **`2 vcores and 2 GB ram`**. I have installed **Elasticsearch & kibana**. For extensions, I have installed Heartbeat and Metricbeat. The database I'm working with is mongo DB and all my data is no-SQL. I feed my engine from my MongoDB cluster which is in my local machine with a script. I feed my engine and run the queries from my app and also from the console. So far so good. Everything is fine. Well, the cluster is always yellow it is not green.

The problem starts after hitting multiple requests on the engine. After 50 or 60 search queries the data just disappears. Well somehow my engine is forcefully dumping my indices and it's not being able to restore those data ( obviously I have no snapshot and no restore point ) and I keep getting lose those data. I have to manually feed the engine again and again. Well at first I had 1 GB ram so I thought upgrading would fix the issue but after upgrading to 2 GB ram it didn't stop. Well, now the data stays there for some more time.

So here are my DB configs.

- I have 70K + no SQL documents.
- Which contains text and geo_point types
- I make post request on my engine through my front end application.
- I don't have logstash installed, but metricbeat is not showing any error logs.
- All my elastic search engine setup is for  **`Testing purposes`** this is **`not the production mode`**.
- We will upgrade when we go to the production mode.

So I need to know

- **What is the reason behind this and**
- **how to prevent this huge data loss**

So please help me or just suggest how to solve this huge problem.

 Thank you

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? I've been having the same problem with AWS ElasticSearch randomly losing all its indexes.

Comment: I think your data was being hacked, you should try adding a password on your cluster or take some security measures. my problem was that I didn't have any password protection so someone was dumping my data. later when I added password I never lost my data again.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally first thing you should do is to make cluster green.

To see the exact elasticsearch error that is causing this situation, you should look at elasticsearch.log file. It will contain exact error causing it.

One way to keep cluster data safe is to take regular snapshots and restore incase of data loss. Details of snapshots procedure can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/modules-snapshots.html).